# map function is not getting called in Apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have written `map` function which is not getting executed.

Below is my code, which is correct syntactically but not getting executed.

```
Dataset<TransactionPritmAndSummarySparkVO> currencyConvertedDS =
    filteredExOutputDS.map(vo -> dummyMap(vo), txnPritmAndSummaryOutputEncoder);

currencyConvertedDS.show();

private static TransactionPritmAndSummarySparkVO dummyMap(TransactionPritmAndSummarySparkVO vo) {
    System.out.println("SUMMARY_ID is " + vo.getSUMMARY_ID());
    return vo;
}
```

**Expected output** is to show result of `currencyConvertedDS` dataset with 6 rows in logs.

**Actual result:** One row is being shown with no values in it.

This is a simple map operation, I am not sure why it is unable to execute it?

**Spark version used: 2.3.0**

Comment: Do you mean you have implemented the `map` method? If so, show us the code, how do you expect us to help otherwise?

Comment: are you sure that "filteredExOutputDS" contains more than one row? and probably there is something wrong with Encoder